# Understanding text size on different resolution image in canvas android

Tags: android, text, android-canvas

When I tried same text size on top different resolution bitmaps on a canvas. Same text size looked small on a bigger resolution and bigger on a small resolution image. Please Help me understand this.

Comment: You should use dp as unit.

Comment: see `android.util.TypedValue#applyDimension`

Comment: Any solution for this, I'm facing a similar kind of issue : (

Answer (score 1):

You need to set proper text size for your `Paint`, that accounts for density. `Paint.setTextSize(float)`, takes in a float value. You need to ensure that this is not a constant value, but one that accounts for density.

How to get the density? You get that information from `DisplayMetrics.scaledDensity` or `DisplayMetrics.density`. Once you have this value, multiply this with the fontSize and set that value as the text size. Somthing like the below.

```
 Paint.setTextSize(density * 10f);
```

This way a text with `10f` font size will look the same in all devices with varying densities. You can find more information on `density` and `scaledDensity` here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#scaledDensity

Comment: The screen density is same. It's the resolution of the image which is varying. On same device, drawing a text over a large resolution image results in small size text whereas drawing a text over a small resolution image results in large size text.

Answer (score -1):

This is way you can make all text uniform size in all device.

```
canvas.drawText(hourText, getPx(TEXT_SIZE, activity), getPx(TEXT_SIZE / 3, activity), nPaint);

public static int getPx(int dp, Activity activity) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        float logicalDensity = metrics.density;
        return (int) Math.ceil(dp * logicalDensity);
    }
```

Comment: The second and third argument in drawText are x and y coordinates where your text need to be drawn how dose it even affect the text size????

Comment: provide your drawtext method

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText%28java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29

Comment: becz i fixed this issue

Comment: i asked your implementation

Comment: I didn't implement drawText I used the above implementation.